# Why does this pattern of [.]* not work if the matched string is not at the starting position?

Tags: python, regex

I tried some regex matching in Python. For example:

```py
s = "aaabbb123123"
print(re.search("[ab]*", s))

output : <re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='aaabbb'> --> Ok, it's good.
```

```py
s = "aaabbb123123"
print(re.search("[.]*", s))

output : <re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''> --> why not "aaabbb123123"?
```

```py
s = "aaabbb123123"
print(re.search("[123]*", s))

output : <re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''> --> why not "123123"?
```

My question is why the pattern "[anything]*" doesn't work if the matched string is not at the starting position of the target string.

Comment: The matches are succeeding, but the `*` means that an empty string is a permissible match. Use `+` instead?

Comment: The first/leftmost match (fundamental part of matching) is more important than the longest match (behaviour of individual quantifiers). Also, `[.]` is a literal period, different from `.`. Are you trying to get the longest match anywhere? Or just any non-empty match?

Comment: Greediness means individual phases of the matching process attempt to match as much as possible, not that the search attempts to find the longest possible match for the overall regex.

Comment: Also `.` isn't special inside a character class.

Comment: In your second and third cases you are looking for 0 or more of a period (case 2) or the numbers 1, 2, or 3 (case 3). In both cases that matches at the beginning of the string because there are 0 periods and 0 of 1,2 or 3. Your first case gives a longer result because the first character is an a, so the regex keeps matching until it can't any more.

Comment: Your second case should actually be `.*` which will match the entire string (`.` inside a character class matches a literal `.`, not any character). For your third case, using a `+` forces the regex to look for a 1, 2 or 3, and having found one, it will then keep matching until there are no more of those characters.

Comment: I got it. I didn't notice leftmost is prior to longest, and [.] means a set containing a char '.'. Thank you guys.